# Append column from one dataframe to another dataframe and change its name

Tags: r

**My data**

I have two dataframes in R. One of them contains multiple columns and 19 rows. The second one contains only one column (`participant_code`), also with 19 rows.

**What I want**

I would like to append the column `participant_code` to the main dataframe. At the same time, the name of the column should change to simply `participant`.

**What I tried**

I tried using this code:

```
main_df$participant = small_df[1] # this should access the single column in the dataframe
```

**My problem**

Even though this code works, the new column is named `participant.participant_code`, which is basically a combination of the old and the new name. How should I change my code to achieve the result I want?

*Note*: I don't want to replace `small_df[1]` by `small_df$actual_name_of_column` because the name of the column is expected to change in the future and I don't want to change my code later, so I'm trying to avoid using a direct reference, if that makes sense.

Comment: if you are using `\`$<-\`` ensure that the right hand side is a vector. ie `main_df$participant = small_df[, 1]`. Note the comma before1 within the brackets of `small_df`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple reproducible example of the problem:

```
df1 = data.frame(x = 1:5)
df2 = data.frame(y = 1:5)
df1$new = df2[1]
#   x y
# 1 1 1
# 2 2 2
# 3 3 3
# 4 4 4
# 5 5 5
```

However, if we use `[<-` instead of `$<-`, you get the desired result

```
df1[, 'new'] = df2[1]
#   x new
# 1 1   1
# 2 2   2
# 3 3   3
# 4 4   4
# 5 5   5
```

Or, `[[` drops names, whereas `[` does not.  So we can also use:

```
df1$new = df2[[1]]
```

Or, extracting the column as a vector also works:

```
df1$new = df2[, 1]
```